# How to change highlight color of selection in search tab in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, themes

In Eclipse 4.2 on Windows 7, in the search results tab, the selected search result has an unpleasant light color that makes it hard to read the text under it:

[image]

I have not been able to locate where this color is. Any ideas?

Comment: is that not tied to your system highlight color? im using eclipse on windows, and that highlight is the same as any highlight box (icons, etc) in windows

Comment: Is there a way to override with that with a setting in Eclipse?

Comment: Within eclipse specifically? Don't think so -- but I really don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your Themes & Appearance settings.

Go to Windows > Preferences > General > Appearance

You will get options for Color themes, and label decorations.

you can download more themes from [eclipse theme plugin](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin)

Its operating system's default selection color, you cannot change that thro' eclipse. Although if you select a light color theme, you will get black or dark color text and you will be able to see the text more clearly over this light blue background. or you can manually choose dark shades of colors for text.

Comment: I am looking to find out where the setting is for that specific item. So far, I have been unable to find it. I know about color themes and where the various color options are, but I don't know which is for the item I mentioned.

Comment: @kurzweil4 Its operating system's default selection color, you cannot change it thro' eclipse settings. change your theme  to lighter color or make font darker.